# bash: sed and/or grep having problems with specific line

Tags: bash, file, sed, grep, cat

For a course called 'Programming Techniques', I have to scan a file with lines having the following format:

`[IP-Address] - - [[Date and time]] "GET [some URL]" [HTML reply code] [some non-interesting number]`

An example:

`129.232.223.206 - - [30/Apr/1998:22:00:02 +0000] "GET /images/home_intro.anim.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 60349`

My task is to scan all lines and extract from it the HTTP reply code **only** if this code is not equal to 200.

We have to use the command line. The following almost works:

`cat file.out | sed 's/^.*\"[[:space:]]//' | sed 's/[[:space:]].*//' | grep -v '200' | sort | uniq 1> result1.txt`

First, read in the file, remove everything up until the second `"` and the space after it, remove everything from the first space to the end, remove lines with `200`, sort the numbers, remove duplicates, and send the remaining numbers to a file.

This produces the following output:

```
-
206
26.146.85.150ÀüŒÛ/ HTTP/1.0" 404 305
302
304
400
404
500
```

As we can see, it **almost** works. There is one line causing trouble:

`26.146.85.150 - - [01/May/1998:16:47:28 +0000] "GET /images/home_fr_phra><HR><H3>\C0\FC\BC\DB/ HTTP/1.0" 404 305`

This line causes the weird third output-line. What is wrong with this line? The only thing I can think of is the part `\C0\FC\BC\DB`. Backslashes always seem to cause trouble. So, what part of my command conflicts with this line?

Also, I noticed that if I switched `sort` and `uniq`, the file does get sorted, but duplicates do not get removed. Why?

(By the way, I'm relatively new to using the command line for the purposes described above.)

Comment: if awk is allowed, you can easily get the second field from the end.

Comment: `uniq` only detects adjacent duplicates; you need to `sort` first to bring the dupes together

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know `uniq` only detects adjacent duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

So, this looks like encoding SNAFU. If I'm not mistaken, what's happening is:

1. You're using an UTF-8 locale,
2. The input file does not contain valid UTF-8,
3. `sed` attempts to read the file as UTF-8 because of the aforementioned locale, and
4. `sed` breaks because of this (in particular, `.` does not match the offending bytes).

The stuff with the backslashes denotes a series of four bytes by their hex values, that is `C0 FC BC DB`. This is not valid UTF-8-encoded data.<sup>1</sup>

Given an UTF-8 locale, (GNU) `sed` interprets input as UTF-8, and `.` matches a valid UTF-8 character. It does not match invalid byte sequences. You can see this by running

```
echo -e '\xc0\xfc\xbc\xdb' | sed 's/.//g'
```

in a UTF-8 locale and noticing that the output is not empty. I am inclined to agree that this behavior is a bit of a nuisance, but here we are.

Since you don't seem to rely on any Unicode features, the solution could be to run `sed` with a non-UTF-8 locale, such as `C`. In your case:

```
cat file.out | LC_ALL=C sed 's/^.*\"[[:space:]]//' \
             | LC_ALL=C sed 's/[[:space:]].*//' \
             | grep -v '200' \
             | sort \
             | uniq 1 \
             > result1.txt
```

(line breaks added for readability). By the way, you could conflate the two `sed` commands to a single one as follows:

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/^.*\"[[:space:]]//; s/[[:space:]].*//'
```

<sup>1</sup>  `c0` would indicate a two-byte UTF-8 code whose uppermost five bits are zero, which already makes no sense since it could be encoded as plain ASCII, and `fc` does not begin with the `10` bits in the uppermost half-nibble that the UTF-8 encoding would require there. So, although I am unsure what exactly their encoding is, it is definitely not UTF-8.

Comment: It not only works, the command is also faster than it was before. This will be quite helpful when I don't just have a single file, but 25 files containing 4 gigabytes of data.

Comment: You could further conflate it with `LC_ALL=C sed 's/^.*\"[[:space:]]//; s/[[:space:]].*//; /200/d' file.out | sort -u > result1.txt`, I believe. Or `/^200$/d`; even though HTTP status codes with more than three digits should not appear, I like stricter regexes better (this would also apply to `grep -v '^200$'`).